# Python 2.7.8 Tkinter Gui with image, button and text

Tags: python, image, python-2.7, button, tkinter

I'm creating a splash screen that will be the introduction to my program. I have managed to place an image on the screen but as soon as I add a button nothing comes up, not even the `tkinter` window.

What I'm trying to do is have an image on the top of the window, under it a text box with my name "Bob Johns" then another button that says `"Enter"`, which will take the user to another section of the program (i.e. start the application). All of this aligned to the centre.

Here's what I have so far:

```
from Tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import os

#create the window
root = Tk()

#modify root window
root.title("Labeler")
root.geometry("500x500")#Width x Height

img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("test.gif"))
panel = Label(root, image = img)
panel.pack(side = "bottom", fill = "both", expand = "yes")

#If i add this section the program goes awol--------------
app = Frame(root)
app.grid()
button1 = Button(app, text = "This is a button")
button1.grid()
#---------------------------------------------------------


#Start the event loop
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Swap interface on button press](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26298591/swap-interface-on-button-press)

Comment: *(**TL;DR**: don't mix `grid` and `pack`)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is mixing `pack` and `grid`.

Use only one layout manager at once (at least for the widgets who share same parent)

```
...
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("test.gif"))
panel = Label(root, image = img)
panel.pack(side="top", fill = "both", expand = "yes")

app = Frame(root)
app.pack(side='bottom')
button1 = Button(app, text = "This is a button")
button1.pack()
...
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked like a charm. Just tried to add text using -         master = Tk()
w = Label(master, text="Hello, world!")
w.pack()         but it creates a new tkinter window, how do i place it within the same one? (p.s. cant get the code thiing to work)

Comment: @user3423572, Please post it as a separate question.

Comment: That was part of my original question but okay

Comment: @user3423572, In short, instead of making another `Tk` object, reuse the old `Tk` object. (See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15995920/2225682) to know how to remove widgets)

Comment: @user3423572, Search for `tkinter splash` will give you hint.

Comment: I tried the topic you linked but all i managed to do was delete the button and the text was still on another window. I'll post a new question as I now have another issue. Thanks for the help

Comment: @user3423572, I made a simple script based on your code. I wish it help you understand what I meant in the previous comment.: http://pastebin.com/BmXuRtKS

Comment: Thank you ever so much, that helped me out a ton. I managed to expand the code you sent and add textboxes, drop down menus and plaintext within the same window. Just got some formatting issues but I can sort that another time. Thanks once again!