# Python, Tkinter, and SQLite3 interface general strategy

Tags: python-2.7, sqlite, tkinter

I am working on a GUI that will access 4 or more tables in a database for a small used car sales/repair shop.
The interface requires being able to switch back and forth between different viewing and entry screens with out losing any information entered.
For example, a person should be able to be in the middle of entering a new vehicle and be able to switch over to viewing the parts inventory with out losing the progress of entering a new vehicle. Interruptions like this are common in small shops, so having the shop change it's MO will not be reasonable.

I have chased this around experimenting with toplevel windows, withdrawing, lifting, etc. The ideal thing would be something like a tabbed browser or the tabs in Excel.
What method of handling windows, frames, or widgets do people prefer for doing this?

Is there a way to stack frames one on top of another so that they obstruct the frame underneath?
frame_A has 10 widgets.
frame_B has 5 widgets.
Some_buttons to withdraw/lift the frames for viewing/editing.
can I put frame_A directly ontop of frame_B with out the widgets in frame_B making the widgets in frame_A shift around?

Comment: This question is too broad, but you might find e.g. this useful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26213779/3001761

Comment: @jonrsharpe I very much disagree that the question is too broad. A Google search will generates a vast number of questions along these lines, almost all of them answered poorly because the person did not start out asking this very question - they just started writing code until they got stumped. Please remove the down vote, others might find this useful. Thank you for the link, it is very much like what I had started on, but much better than what I had. Your link is by far the best answer on how to switch/hide frames/widgets with out losing entries.

Comment: You're entitled to your opinion (and I mine). That being said, you ask *two* questions, one of which is explicitly opinion-based and the other of which is either yes/no or a request for code. SO questions, of whatever quality, are not the only option; you can also do your own research ("tkinter stack frames" and "tkinter tabbed" would be good starting points).

Answer (score 0):

Tkinter has notebook tabs, by way of the ttk module.

Tkinter also gives you enough tools to create your own tab-like interface if you wish. If you use grid or place you can stack frames on top of each other and change which one is on top.

Comment: Thank you. I have not played with ttk yet, I'm still working on my fluency with tk. I will probably use the solution linked above to manage the UI, but being able to have multiple tabs open in each frame will be very useful.