# How do I navigate from one python gui program to another?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

Here's an excerpt for a main menu using Python Tkinter

```
master = Tk()

lbl = Label(master, text = "Main Menu:")
lbl.grid(row=0,column=1)


def list():
    import list

listb = Button(master, text = "Patient List", command=list, width=10)
listb.grid(row=1, column=1)
```

There's a button "Patient List" that when pressed, opens a window specified from a different python file.

My problem is that the Main Menu window suffers a bug where the window will collapse. The new window comes out fine, but after closing it, I can't use my Main Menu.

Also, on my other buttons. The Main Menu doesn't collapse, but let's say I have a button *Add Patient* and after clicking it, the *Add Patient* window appears. It's functional. And then I close it, either using the quit button I programmed in it, or the close button. The Main Menu won't open the *Add Patient* window again.

So how can I smoothly navigate from one python program to another? Without the main menu collapsing. While being able to open a window over and over again.

My *Patient List* program has a lot of customized gui programming in it. I think it's because I use a grid in my Main Menu, and it's not a grid in my *Patient List*. But it shouldn't be affecting the Main Menu because they're supposed to be separate programs.

Comment: Calling your own module *and* function `list` is not a great idea, perhaps start by changing that?

Comment: same thing. Say I renamed it to look like this "def plist(): import patlist" It's the same thing.

Comment: Yes, but then readers of your question don't have to spend time wondering why you've named them like that! Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. You may also find http://stackoverflow.com/q/26213549/3001761 useful.

Answer (score 0):

When doing such program with TKinter I generally use Screen classes.

To your example it would be for example:
"MainScreen", "AddPatienScreen", ...

All are subclass of the Frame tkinter class.
My Tk app only display one screen and furnish function to destroy and replace one screen by another one.

I have not access to any code now, but I invite yourself to try this approach if you understand it. It lead to well separated code and had good results.

I may provide you a very short example if required.

Comment: Obviously, this pattern let you add some functionalities such as "backward/forward" screen navigation by retaining a fixed size list of screen object that was displayed before. May be useful.